# arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute and a variable

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I have to create a folder from a Shapefile of the municipal boundaries and put the folders (line and point) of the municipalities in it.

I managed to create a loop that creates a folder with the name of my municipality but I can't select the data included in the municipality.
This comes from the expression to select the municipality but I can't find the solution.

I created a list of municipalities.
All my data are shapes.

```
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(Commune_IGN_Layer, 'NEW_SELECTION', '[NOM_COMMUN] = {}'.format(Liste_Commune[a]))
```

Does anyone know how to put the expression SQL as a variable in this selection?

Here's my code:

```py
    """5- Creation of the file of the day for importing data"""

    #Declaration of the location of the file for the creation of the day record"
    Emplacement = r"C:\Users\nh\Desktop\DEV_ArcGis\EXPORT_GIRES"

    #DATE , variable allowing to have the name of the future folder where
    # to create the folders of the data of the communes in order to avoid
    # the duplications the use of the hour allows differentiation
    Date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S')

    #Creation of the folder of the day"
    DossierDuJour =  os.path.join(Emplacement,Date)
    os.makedirs(DossierDuJour)

    """6 - Creation of files and data specific to each municipality """
    #Script allowing to list the name of the commune of the field NOM_COMMUN ,
    # !!!! warning there shouldn't be any special characters,
    #Indice [0] allows you to remove the tuple index from the list in order to have only the tuple name.,
    #The name is then used to create the name of the municipality's folder
    Commune_IGN_Layer =r"C:\Users\nh\Desktop\DEV_ArcGis\TEMP\COMMUNE_IGN_Layer.shp"
    
    Liste_Commune = []
    
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Commune_IGN_Layer, ["NOM_COMMUN"]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:

        #6.1 - Creation of the folder for the municipality
        DossierCommune = os.makedirs(os.path.join(DossierDuJour,(row[0])))

        #6.2 - Selection of the municipality
        CountyNM = str(row[0])

        #Add municipalities names to my list
        Liste_Commune.append(CountyNM)

    # Number of municipalities in the list
    nb_listeCommune = len(Liste_Commune)
    
    a=0
    while a < nb_listeCommune:


    Com = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(
        Commune_IGN_Layer,
        'NEW_SELECTION',
        '"NOM_COMMUN" = {}'.format(Liste_Commune[a])
    )

    #6.2 - Select and export SOUTERRAIN data of the municipality
    #6.2.1 - Select SOUTERRAIN data of the municipality
    COMMUNE_IGN_Sout= arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation(
        in_layer=Com,
        overlap_type="INTERSECT",
        select_features=SD_EP_SOUTERRAIN_GEOREF,
        search_distance="",
        selection_type="NEW_SELECTION",
        invert_spatial_relationship="NOT_INVERT"
    )

    #6.22 - Export SOUTERRAIN data of the municipality in its folder
    exportSout = arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToShapefile(
        Input_Features=COMMUNE_IGN_Sout,
        Output_Folder=DossierCommune
    )


    #6.3 -Select and export SOUTERRAIN data of the municipality
    #6.3.1 - Select SOUTERRAIN data of the municipality

    #arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(fc, 'NEW_SELECTION', row[0])

    #6.32 - Export SOUTERRAIN data of the municipality in its folder
    a=a + 1
```

Comment: Please post your question in English, otherwise a lot of users wont be able to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

To select data you need to do a selection on a *layer* object, you are attempting to select on a featureclass. Your variable `Commune_IGN_Layer` is not a layer object it is simply a path to a featureclass, in your case, a shapefile. To create a layer which is a valid input to the select by Attribute tool you need to call the [make feature layer tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm).

Review the code sample at the end of the help page as that will show you how to use the tool and the resulting layer.

Comment: Bonjour, Je suis dessolé mais je pense ne pas avoir compris ce que vous voulez dire par couche d'entité. J'ai transformé mes données en .lyr mais cela ne change rien. Pouvez me donner un nouveau conseil pour débloquer la situation ? Cordialement

Comment: @NicolasHerve a .lyr file is just the symbology it's not the data and is saved externally to the MXD. A feature layer is a layer object it understands selections, a featureclass is the data on your disk and is unable to understand a selection, so you need to create a feature layer object from the featureclass so you can do selections